# A question to numbers Sylow - a paper of M. Hall

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In [[M. Hall, 1967]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869367900762), M. Hall has a following result. We denote $n_p(G)$ the number of $p$-Sylow subgroup in a finite group $G$.

**Theorem 2.2.** The number $n_p(G)$ in a finite group $G$ is the product of factors of the following two kinds:
(i) the number $n_p(S)$ in a simple group $S$ and
(ii) a prime power $q^t$ where $q^t\equiv1\mod p.$

I'm trying to figure out what $S$ has to do with $G.$ Can $S$ be a subgroup of $G$? I'm still not sure. Futhermore, I'm trying to (i), too. I was suggesting that a prime power $q^t$ dividing the order of a chief factor $T$ of $G$ but I'm still check it.

Comment: I'm writing an answer to your first question, but I don't understand what you mean by "I'm trying to (i)".  Could you clarify?

Comment: Presumably you have attempted to read the proof of this theorem. It would make more sense if you indicated which parts of the proof are causing you problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the statement of the theorem is concerned, the simple group(s) $S$ could be completely arbitrary.  However, as far as I can tell, the only simple groups that actually come up are subquotients of $G$ (i.e. quotients of subgroups).  For example, the fourth sentence of the proof expresses $n_p$ as the product of the numbers of Sylow $p$-subgroups of three subquotients:  $G/K$, $K$, and $N_{PK}(P \cap K)/(P \cap K)$.  If any of these three is simple, we may take it as an $S$.  If not (and if all three mentioned subquotients are strictly smaller than $G$), then we proceed by induction, possibly later encountering some smaller simple groups.

Comment: Oh, $S$ can be a subgroup of one of $G/K,K$ and $\mathbf{N}_{PK}(P\cap K)/(P\cap K).$ In [Iris Koster, 2015, page 6](https://mat.polsl.pl/groups/talks/Koester.pdf), it had been that a prime power $q^t$ dividing the order of a chief factor $T$ of $G$ and $q^t\equiv 1\mod p.$